# Launching Cordova App from Contact List

Tags: cordova, contacts, launch

I am having a Cordova Map App, and planning to launch/open it when someone clicks Address field on the Contact List. Currently it opens Google Map app, but I would like that kind of launch to happen for my App. Could someone support me, please. I am better in HTML5 & JS, but not so great on Android. Is intent is the way to do ? Or i need to get AccountManager support from Google.

Answer (score 0):

To change the default app that's associated with a particular app feature (i.e., Contacts address -> Google Maps) I believe you'll need to change the feature's intent programmatically, and for security reasons, that's not something you can do on Android as far as I know.

Comment: I could use intent for my own app & when clicking the contact list address, it asks for apps (like Google Map / my App). So partially successful. But I am interested in something similar to Whatsapp icon on contact list when my entry gets unique launch. Any help.